# In Xcode, how do I copy a xib file without copying outlet references

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib

I have a xib file of a table cell layout. I have 4 more cell layouts I need to create which are similar to layout 1 in structure, but not in content. The easiest, for me, would be if I could just copy the "layout" without the outlet references and modify the differences manually. Each different xib file will have a different corresponding swift file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy paste the xib file as any file ( Do **ctrl-c** while you're selecting the xib class like in left rectangle)  , change it's name and class , and disconnect the outlets like this by clicking **X**

[image]

Comment: Do you mean I should ctrl-c while actually marking the class as you have marked it in the left rectangle, pr should I copy it as in file -> duplicate? Also where do I get a presentation of all the outlets (right image) - that view makes this merthod very easy!

Comment: ctrl-c is an alternative , you can select the xib file itself from project hierarchy and go to file -> duplicate then rename the file as you want click Save , then go to the new xib and change it's class , after you also make a duplicate of the swift file associated with the xib , then disconnect the X outlets

Answer (score 0):

Outlets are part of the xib that defines your cell and have unique identifiers, you can try to open it as an XML file (right click > open as > source code) and search for an outlet
For example : 
`<outlet property="imageView" destination="S84-Xm-qhg" id="5Kc-ew-jDG"/>`

I also think that its better to follow Sh_Khan answer by copying and disconnecting the existing outlets, using the interface builder, and letting xcode handle the disconnection of outlets.

Comment: Hi Spencer, 

Thanks for your suggestion. It provided me with some understanding of how the xib files work. I did however go with Sh_Khans answer as it seemed a bit "cleaner" as you also indicate.